# Is it possible to display conditional HTML based on page name in wordpress?

Tags: php

I added a bit of custom HTML code to a website. Everything works just great. I am trying to display this HTML code based on the page name. I looked at some resources online and wrote out the code but it does not work. I have also checked online and I am only seeing ways to conditionally add CSS and JS. Is this something that is possible to do and how do I go about doing this?

```
My code
<?php
            global $wpdb;               
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'category_name' => 'featured-posts',
));
  $posts =  $query -> posts;
  if ( is_page('Featured Posts') ){
   foreach ($posts as $post) {  
      echo '
      
<div class="slider-container">
     <h4 class="slider-header">
       <span class="slider-header_text">Trending</span>
     </h4>

  <div class="slider">
      
   <div class="carousel-container">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="track">  
        <div class="card-container">
        <a href="'.$post->guid.'" class="card">
            <div class="img">
             <img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post -> ID, 'thumbnail' ).'" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
               <h5>'.$post->post_title.'</h5>
            </div>
          </a>
         </div>
       
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="nav">
      <button class="prev">
       <i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="next">
       <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>';
  }
  } 
  
  
                    
  ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of echoing a whole bunch of html you can close your php tags and just write html as normal.

for example:

```
<?php
...
...
...
foreach ($posts as $post) {
?>
    <!-- here goes the html -->
<?php
}
?>
```

On the otherhand you mention in your question that you are trying to display html based on a page name.

You can do this by making a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page)

Comment: I would do this but I added the code in the theme header file.

Comment: Well then the first part of my answer should suffice. Did you need further explanation?